# Read healthkit heart rate when app is running in background using notifications

Tags: swift, apple-push-notifications, healthkit, ios12, background-fetch

Question 1. When a new heart rate sample is added to the healthkit, I want to read this sample immediately even when the app is running in background by using notifications method.Is this really possible, reliably?

So far, I tried the background fetch method to query for new heart rate sample added to the heathkit. However, the fetch does not fire reliably and it is very inconsistent. Hence my app does not receive the new added data immediately or sometimes nothing at all. I tried both simulated version and also on a real hardware.Debugging is also a challenge.

Question 2: I want to read the heart rate in my app when the phone is locked. Is this possible? Many threads says it is not possible due to encryption of data during locked period. But these answers seems to be old threads. Are there any definite answer to such a vital question?

There are many numerous threads without any clarity at all.Apple documentation is garbage. Such hinderance does not encourage beginners like me. Any suggestions would be appreciated.